# Learning GUIs - setContentPane() method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm learning GUI programming in java, and trying to modify an existing programme to add a vertical left-hand panel containing buttons to my main frame.

The main method is below. Currently, the MainPanel class extends JPanel and contains the main components of the programme (a basic game). I want to create a new panel to the right of the game.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sokuban");
        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

I understand (I think!) how to add the buttons - I'm not stuck there.

I've tried things like:

```
    frame.add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

(MyPanel() being a new class that extends JPanel)

```
        window.setContentPane(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
```

(wouldn't compile)

What I am stuck with is a) whether I should try to create two JPanels contained within my JFrame, and then position them side by side using BoxLayout (??). Or, b) whether I should create a second JPanel to sit within the MainPanel, and somehow rearrange it there?

Also, despite reading the literature, I don't understand what the setContentPane() method is doing. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The content pane is the component which sits inside the window.

Answer (score 5):

By default JFrame already has a JPanel as a ContentPane, which is using BorderLayout.
So you can just do:

```
frame.add(new ButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The JFrame setLayout() and add() method are really just shortcuts for jFrame.getContentPane.setLayout() and jFrame.getContentPane.add().
So in your code, you were setting the layout of the default content panel (a JPanel), just before replacing it with your MainPanel, so it had no effect.

The setContentPane() method allows you to replace the content panel of the JFrame, but it is rarely necessary.

Comment: *"but it is rarely necessary"* This really depends on what you're doing... Sometimes you have to or want to extend a component to get some behavior out of it such that the default content pane won't do. But it's true, a lot of times I see stuff like `class MyProgram extends JPanel { public static void main...`, extending a component to contain program logic which is a bad style.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create a new panel to the right of the game.

No need to write this:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

You can simply use these code snippet:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

In case you want that right panel to spread throughout the remaining area of frame.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```